# Show and Hide option for DIV(needs modification)

Tags: javascript, html, css

### JavaScript - Show or hide a div using a link and CSS

Here am using java script to show and hide DIV

### code

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display = '';
            return false;" 
       href="" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px dotted blue;">
        Show more...</a>
    <br />
    <div id="div_name2" style="display:none;margin:15px 15px 0px 15px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #aaa;">
        This is more information placed in our hidden div.  
        When you click on the "hide" link this DIV area will disappear:  
        <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display = 'none';
                return false;" href="" 
           style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px dotted blue;">hide</a>
    </div>
```

this is the code am using

- now what i need is when page is loaded i need the `DIV` to be visible
- how do i make `DIV` visible when page is loaded

### ERROR

when i load this page the div is hidden how do i make div visible???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display = 'block';
            return false;" 
       href="" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px dotted blue;">
        Show more...</a>
    <br />
    <div id="div_name2" style="display:block;margin:15px 15px 0px 15px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #aaa;">
        This is more information placed in our hidden div.  
        When you click on the "hide" link this DIV area will disappear:  
        <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display = 'none';
                return false;" href="" 
           style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px dotted blue;">hide</a>
    </div>
```

You should give attribute "display:block" to your div to show it when the website is loaded. Now, when you click on your link, you should set display to none to hide div_name2

Comment: and i need to disappear show more option when page is loaded

Comment: when i hide and click show option it doens't display div

Comment: am using two option in hide place i need to load a page bellow in the same page and hide the current div on this when click hide option will this code work or i need to have some changes

Comment: Maybe you will need to change some code. However you can use this example to do it. Remember: 
document.getElementById('nameofyourdiv').style.display = 'block';
to show nameofyourdiv
document.getElementById('nameofyourdiv').style.display = 'none';
to hide nameofyourdiv

Comment: it works but CSS div height doesn't get reduced am using bootstrap am getting empty space but show ,hide option works how do i reduce DIV height